# Crystal reports: using summary field in formula / summing time field in formula

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, crystal-reports-xi

In crystal reports I want to show the *sum* value of *time* objects, i.e. An employee worked in one month three days and on each day a variable amount of hours.

Is there anyway to *sum* a *time* field?

Or as a workaround I could use the time field as an *integer*, sum this and display. But then I would like to change the display format by using a formula. I cant find a way to include summary fields in a formula...

Thanks in advance

PS I am using *CR 2011* (just the program not through *VB* or anything).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot sum a date/time field. You will have to use `datediff("n",{datetime1},{datetime2})` to get a time interval between two date/time fields in minutes.

To use a summary function in a formula, you can use this `sum({@YourMinutesFormula},{FieldYouAreGroupingOn})`

You may omit the second parameter if you want the summation over the entire report instead of a grouping level. Check the Crystal Reports help file for more details on Sum().

Comment: Your solution works indeed. I found out that i had a field stating the time as an integer available. I summed this for the group and transformed this back to a timeformat. Not a nice but it works.